# How to get thumbnail with built-in HttpProvider

Tags: wowza, wowza-transcoder

I test Wowza on trial license and I follow [this article](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?307-How-to-get-thumbnail-images-from-Wowza-Transcoder-with-an-HTTP-Provider) to get a thumbnail from wowza transcoder. My Application name is **live2** and stream name is **test**. Wowza transcoder is turned on and restarted. In wowza streaming engine manager in incoming streams I can see: test rtmp://127.0.0.1:35412 , test_160p local (Transcoder), test_360p local (Transcoder) etc.

But when I enter folowing url in my browser **localhost:8086/transcoderthumbnail?application=live2&streamname=test&format=jpeg&size=320x240**

It doesn't work. Even in logs file there is no mention unless I put in url wrong stream name. What I do wrong?

Comment: Did you add the `com.wowza.wms.transcoder.httpprovider.HTTPTranscoderThumbnail` in your VHost.xml? When you check the startup logs, do you see any mention of the above class?

Comment: @jabal I did, part of  [install-dir]/conf/VHost.xml looks like :                    `-<HTTPProvider>

<BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.transcoder.httpprovider.HTTPTranscoderThumbnail</BaseClass>

<RequestFilters>transcoderthumbnail*</RequestFilters>

<AuthenticationMethod>none</AuthenticationMethod>

</HTTPProvider>`  In logs i can see only mention when I put in browser wrong stream name, which is not currently transcoded (for example `tes` instead `test`): `HTTPTranscoderThumbnail.onHTTPRequest[live2/_definst_]: Stream not found: tes`

Comment: When I put in browser correct url I should expect to see in logs something like: `HTTPTranscoderThumbnail#GrabResult.onGrabFrame[live/_definst_/myStream]: Image result: format:jpeg size:320x240 ` but I can't find this message.

Comment: What kind of video codec is used in the incoming stream? In the logs, do you see a decoder-video-start and an encoder-video-start log events for your test stream?

Comment: @Michelle-B, following this guide [https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?304-How-to-set-up-and-run-Wowza-Transcoder-for-live-streaming#basicTest  there should be `Comment server INFO 200 TranscoderSessionNative.loadLibrary: Load Transcoder list: C:\Program Files (x86)\Wowza Media Systems\Wowza Media Server 4.0.0/lib-native/win64/transcoder.list` mesage in the logs but there isn't.  What could be the problem?

Comment: You should be able to safely ignore its absence, as long as you see the decoder-video-start and encoder-video-start log lines.